# Append a text file in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to read a text file using Prolog and then append that file. I used following code to do that.

```
readWord(InStream,W) :- 
   get0(InStream,Char),
   checkCharAndReadRest(Char,Chars,InStream),
   atom_chars(W,Chars), write(W),write('\n').

checkCharAndReadRest(10,[],_) :- !. % Return
checkCharAndReadRest(32,[],_) :- !. % Space
checkCharAndReadRest(-1,[],_) :- !. % End of Stream
checkCharAndReadRest(end_of_file,[],_) :- !.

checkCharAndReadRest(Char,[Char|Chars],InStream) :-
   get0(InStream,NextChar),
   checkCharAndReadRest(NextChar,Chars,InStream).

writeWord(end_of_file). 
writeWord(X) :-
   write(X),nl.

readFile:-
    open('output.txt', read, In),
    repeat,
    readWord(In,W),
    writeWord(W),
    W == end_of_file, !,
    close(In).

adding :-
   open('output.txt', append, In),
   write(In, 'abc'),
   close(In).
```

Example:

> Text file data -
>
> Ann
>
> csu2280
>
> 23
>
> end_of_file

Required output –

> saman
>
> csu2280
>
> 23
>
> abc
>
> end_of_file

But I got the answer as

> saman
>
> csu2280
>
> 23
>
> end_of_fileabc

How can I get the required answer?

Comment: You are using outdated/deprecated built-ins: Use `get_code/1` in place of `get0/1`.

Comment: get0 returns -1 at end_of_file - maybe your readFile doesn't close it ?